# How to fetch mutilple fields using distinct in MongoDb and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get multiple fields from MongoDb using NodeJS.I am using distinct function to get name and phone number from a documents where order status is pending.

Below is my code:

```
const coll = client.db("My_db").collection("Orders");
            coll.distinct("name","phone",{order_status:"pending"},(function(err,docs){

               let output = docs.map(r => ({'name':r,'phone':r}));
                  res.send(output);       
            }));
```

It is showing error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.
```

Someone please let me know how can I get desired results.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate to get multiple distinct fields.

```
coll.aggregate([
{ "$match": {
     "order_status": "pending"
}},
{ "$group": { "_id": { name: "$name", phone: "$phone" } } } 
]).exec().then(docs =>{
 console.log(docs);
 // all your other functionality and response
 }).catch(error=>{
 console.log(error) // catching errors if occurred
 })
```

after this aggregation i don't think you will be needing an map function but you can console.log and check it. if needed the map function will be pretty much the same.

Hope this helps. GOOD LUCK :)

Comment: What do I console.log() here

Comment: you can chain an exec method which will return a promise and you can catch in a then block.i'll update my answer for you.